# html background with image & color

Tags: css, html

Hi i was going through a website where they used a very unique (according to me) background. they are mixing a color with an image and using it as background. the image is like [image: Which is light in color]

Then they are mixing some yellow color in it & it become like this [image]

When i went through the code they were using something like this

```
background: #f6b93c url(bg1.png);
```

but it did not work for me!
Please help me out?

Comment: if you have try this please share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: @Fags did you read his question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yA8Yf/

Answer (score 3):

That is nothing but a short hand syntax

```
background: #f6b93c url(bg1.png);
```

So the above code simply means

```
background-color: #f6b93c;
background-image: url(bg1.png);
```

For more info on [`background`](http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/) short hand syntax

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQjuQ/)

Comment: It doesn't *quite* mean that. The other values get set back to their defaults. *Given a valid declaration, for each layer the shorthand first sets the corresponding layer of each of ‘background-image’, ‘background-position’, ‘background-size’, ‘background-repeat’, ‘background-origin’, ‘background-clip’ and ‘background-attachment’ to that property's initial value, then assigns any explicit values specified for this layer in the declaration. Finally ‘background-color’ is set to the specified color, if any, else set to its initial value.* — http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

Comment: @Quentin yes it does, but it's a short hand to declare the color as well as the image together :) many of them have a wrong impression for this syntax, they take it as multiple backgrounds

Comment: @user2131695 yes we got you, that simply overlays the image on the background color, check out the demo I shared, if you cannot get it work, may be the image path is incorrect or your image isn't transparent

Comment: Thanks! i guess there is some transparency problem with image!

Answer (score 1):

a png image with transparency and bg color will do the trick,

Otherwise if it is a jpeg,
 the color will fill the rest of the part(for eg:in a div), the image wont cover.

what was happening with this `background: #f6b93c url(bg1.png);`
fill the color `#f6b93c` then on the top of that place the image, so it was a %0%(for eg.) transparent image, this will end up with a mixer of both

Comment: ok, that is because it was a png image with transparency , so because we set a bg color it shows a mixer of both..

Comment: That i got it, but why it is not happening at my end. please check out this fiddle & suggest any changes http://jsfiddle.net/yA8Yf/

Comment: is your png transparent to some extend..??

Comment: Yes, i have downloaded from that website itself!

Comment: try the code locally! may be some problem with the image link, it works perfectly for me with the same image, same code

Answer (score 0):

with latest CSS3 technology, it is possible to create texured background. Check this out: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#

but it still limited on so many aspect. And browser support is also not so ready.

your best bet is using small texture image and make repeat to that background. you could get some nice ready to use texture image here:

http://subtlepatterns.com

Answer (score 0):

The image bg1.png does not seem to be in baseurl. You should try relative url. eg. if you have image inside 'images' folder, "images/bg1.png" should work.